# How do I mock Graphql queries and set the loader false to test the react component when loading = false with Jest & Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, graphql, enzyme

I'm using codegen on frontend to generate types and using graphql queries to fetch data in this format -

```js
const { data, loading, error } = useSampleQuery({
    variables: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
    }
})
```

I'm using jest & enzyme for testing my react components.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you didn't give a full code example or enough information to give a detailed answer.

Basically you need to mock your Graphql API. If you are using Apollo this is quite easy. Apollo provides you with a `MockedProvider`, which acts like the normal provider, but lets you define test data.

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { GET_DOG_QUERY, Dog } from './dog';

const mocks = []; // We'll fill this in next

it('renders without error', () => {
  const component = TestRenderer.create(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
      <Dog name="Buck" />
    </MockedProvider>,
  );

  const tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree.children).toContain('Loading...');
});
```

You can find this and more examples here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/

As you are also testing an API you kind of leave the area of unit testing. It is more an integration test. If you want to do unit testing you need to decouple the API requests from the component which displays your data.